# Show that $\frac{n!}{4^n}$ tends to infinity by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that (theoretically) the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ infinitely large, if $x_{n} = \frac{n!}{4^n}$.

How to do it?

Normally, I approached like this :

$$x_{n} = \frac{(1 \cdot 2  \cdots n)}{(4 \cdot 4  \cdots 4)} = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdots \frac{n}{4}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdots \frac{n}{4} = \infty$$

But, how to prove it theoretically from the definition?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $n >5$ we have $\frac {n!} {4^{n}} >\frac {(1)(1)(1)(1)(5)(5)...(5)} {4^{n}}=\frac 1 {4^{4}} (\frac 5 4)^{n-4}$ where $5$ is repeated  are $n-4$ times.

Answer (score 0):

We must show that for any $M>0$ there exists  $N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then
$\frac{n!}{4^n} > M$

Apply logarithm to both sides
$$\ln n! - n \ln 4 > \ln M$$
[Stirling's approximation of factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$\ln n! \approx n \ln n - n$$
$$n \ln n - n - n \ln 4 > \ln M$$

If we take
$$N = \left\lfloor\frac{\log (M)}{W\left(\frac{\log (M)}{4 e}\right)}\right\rfloor$$
then for $n>N$ we have $\frac{n!}{4^n} > M$, where $W(x)$ is Lambert function.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \ge 6$ then
$$x_n = \bigl(\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{4}\bigr) \cdot \bigl(\prod_{5 \le k \le n-1} \frac{k}{4} \bigr) \cdot \frac{n}{4} \ge \frac{3}{32} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{n}{4} = \frac{3}{128}n
$$
From the definition, given $B \ge 0$ we must find an integer $N \ge 1$ so that for any integer $n \ge N$ we have $x_n > B$.

Setting $\frac{3}{128}n > B$ and solving we get $n > \frac{128B}{3}$.

So letting $N$ be any positive integer such that $N > \max\{6,\frac{128B}{3}\}$, if $n \ge N$ then it follows that $x_n > B$ and the proof is finished.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show for any $N$ there is an $n$ so that $\frac 14\times \frac 24 \times ......\times \frac n4> N$.

Now for all $k >4$ then $\frac k4 >1$ so the product of infinitely many items all greater than $1$ should tend to $\infty$[1].  Note if $k\ge 5$ then $\frac k4 \ge \frac 54$ and $\frac {n!}{4n} = \frac 14\times \frac 24 \times ......\times \frac n4 \ge \frac {4!}{4^4}\times {\frac 54}^{n-4}$.

And from that it is clear we can do it.  We know that for $a > 1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a^n = \infty$ and and we know $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = \lim_{n-4\to \infty} b_n$ and we know if $k>0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} kb_n = \infty$.  (And if we *don't* know any of those, we certainly have the tools to like our ducks up and shoot them and prove them).

So I say we are done.

But if we want to be formal.  For $K\in R$ if $N > \max (\log_{\frac 54} K,0)$ then for any $n > N$ then $(\frac 54)^n > K$.  For any $n> N_1 = N-\log_{\frac 54}\frac {4!}{4^4}$ then $(\frac 54)^n > \frac K{\frac {4!}{4^4}}$ so $\frac {4!}{4^4}(\frac 54)^n > K$.  And any $n > N_2=N_1 +4$ then $\frac {n!}{4^4} \ge \frac {4!}{4^4}(\frac 54)^{n-4} > K$.

......

[1] "should" being tentative.  $a_n >1$ no more assures $\prod a_n \to \infty$ than $b_n > 0$ assures $\sum b_n \to \infty$. And indeed $\prod a_n = e^{\sum \ln a_n}$ shows they are equivalent statement.  But just as $\sum b_n\ne \infty; b_n >0$ requires $b_n \to 0$, $\prod a_n \ne \infty; a_n > 1$ requires $a_n \to 1$. And that is not the case here.